# Firebase Database unable to retrieve value

Tags: java, android

I am unable to change the text of multiple TextView to the values retrieved from Firebase Realtime Database.

My database looks like: [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8UU7.jpg)

My current code is:

```
public class SearchResult extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView searchResultHSPName,searchResultHSPStatus, searchResultHSPType,searchResultHSPRating;
    Button messageButton;
    private static final String TAG = "SearchResult";
    DatabaseReference rootReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);

        searchResultHSPName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hspNameSearchResultTextView);
        searchResultHSPType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hspTypeSearchResultTextView);
        searchResultHSPRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hspRatingSearchResultTextView);
        searchResultHSPStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hspStatusSearchResultTextView);
        //take the searched name from searchFunction and query db for the user details
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String searchedHSPName = intent.getExtras().getString("SearchFunctionMessage");
        rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference userReference = rootReference.child("HSPUsers");
        userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    HSPUsers user = snapshot.getValue(HSPUsers.class);
                    String userName = user.HSPName;
                    if(userName == searchedHSPName){
                        searchResultHSPName.setText(userName);
                        searchResultHSPStatus.setText(user.HSPStatus);
                        searchResultHSPRating.setText(user.HSPRating);
                        searchResultHSPType.setText(user.HSPType);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

}

And my HSPUsers class is:

```
public class HSPUsers {
    //HSP user contains 4 fields of data UserName, Status,Type,Rating
    public String HSPName,HSPStatus, HSPType,HSPRating;

    //constructor for datasnapshot
    public HSPUsers(){
    }


    public HSPUsers(String username, String status, String type, String rating){
        this.HSPName=username;
        this.HSPStatus=status;
        this.HSPType=type;
        this.HSPRating=rating;
    }


    //get and set methods
    public String getHSPUserName() {
        return HSPName;
    }

    public void setHSPUserName(String HSPUserName) {
        this.HSPName = HSPUserName;
    }

    public String getHSPUserStatus() {
        return HSPStatus;
    }

    public void setHSPUserStatus(String HSPUserStatus) {
        this.HSPStatus = HSPUserStatus;
    }

    public String getHSPUserType() {
        return HSPType;
    }

    public void setHSPUserType(String HSPUserType) {
        this.HSPType = HSPUserType;
    }

    public String getHSPUserRating() {
        return HSPRating;
    }
}

    public String getHSPUserRating() {
        return HSPRating;
    }
}
```

Ideally, i would like to change the textViews to the user's Name/Status/Rating/Type. However, there has been no change to the textviews and i am left with  [UnchangedTextViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr2pZ.png)

Would appreciate any advice on how to change the TextViews to the HSPName/rating/Status/type?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Please paste your codes here and add it to the question and don't send images instead of codes. Thank you. However, what happens now? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The TextView does not any of the User's Name/Rating/Status/Type. The application does not crash though.

Comment: `HSPUsers` is a child of something in your firebase structure? Can you please show the root reference which ends by `HSPUsers`. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the image to show the root reference. Thanks for your help.